# Is it possible to get veal that is not incredibly fatty?

Tags: meat, butchering, veal

I have not had such good success with veal. I prefer leaner meats, and every time I get a cut of veal, it is extremely fatty. Is there a way to get leaner veal? Are there specific cuts I should ask for? If so, where are some places I should look to get better cuts?

Answer (score 2):

The nature of veal, being a milk fed calf, means that the meat is going to be extremely fatty.  It is the nature of the meat and not a function of poor butchering.  If you don't like the flavor I would suggest that almost anything that calls for veal can be made with pork chops or other lean cuts of pork, although you might see a rise in the toughness of the dish as a result.